# how to get different displays in different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Configuration for large screen size]

[image: Configuration for small screen size]

I am trying to create this configuration in css with flexbox. The first image represents the behaviour I would like to get in wide screens, the second one is what I would like to get on small screens. I tryed to achieve that by using flex-wrap: wrap, but the 2 elements still use the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use media queries. When in a small screen you can change the boxes max-width. Remember min-width establishes a minimum but doesn't establish a maximum so the box can grow. You can also acomplish this kind of thing by changing the flex-grow css property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries

This link will help you!